# Is there a way to find the completion of major compaction completion status via hbase client API?

Tags: hbase

I want to trigger major compaction for all the tables in the hbase. Using hbase client API, major compaction is triggered for all the times via admin.majorCompact(tableName). 
1) How to figure out the completion status for the compaction, since hbase client api majorCompact is an Asynchorous process.
2) Is it mandatory to wait until compaction process completion , to query hbase for real time process

Comment: Compaction completion status can be found on the regionserver logs. Still have to find out a proper way to get the status

Answer (score 1):

1) To get the compaction state for a table or region, you can make use of [HBaseAdmin.getCompactionStateForRegion](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#getCompactionStateForRegion-byte:A-)

2) As far as I've seen, read during major compaction will be possible, but we can't expect the response in desired time as Region server will be working on the same data.